# What is the difference between Reference Assemblies and Public Assemblies in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have been investigating some issues with Web Performance Test Plugins in Visual Studio 2013. When adding references to the necessary dlls (e.g. `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework.dll`) I noticed that there are multiple entries for the same dll available in the 'Add References' window. On my system I have five choices for WebTestFramework.

Some of these I see are from earlier versions of Visual Studio which are also installed on my machine. However, I see that some are duplicates, e.g.:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\WebTestFramework.dll`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\WebTestFramework.dll`

I've compared the hashes of these two files and they are identical. So, why are they present in my VS 2013 (v12.0) installation twice? Why is there both a 'ReferenceAssemblies' and a 'PublicAssemblies' folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, ideally the implementation assembly doesn't appear in the list.  But the control over what appears in the list isn't fine-grained enough, it can only be configured by directory, not individual assemblies.  A further constraint is that Microsoft is often forced to pick less than desirable storage locations for an assembly to maintain backwards compatibility with previous VS versions so they don't break existing projects.  And the test frameworks have changed a great deal through the VS versions, took them a while to get all the quirks ironed out.

*Always* pick the reference assembly when one is offered.  They are meant to isolate you from these rapid changes and often *intentionally* are not a copy of the implementation assembly.  You'll get it to work when you pick the implementation assembly but you risk having your test project broken in the next VS version.  YMMV.

Comment: By mistake we have unit tests variously added via C# class library project templates and unit test project templates. The devs that created the class libraries have added references to the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` from `ReferenceAssemblies` although the unit test template adds them from `PublicAssemblies`. The tests run for me in VS 2013, but don't for another dev running VS 2012. Do you know if the version of VS the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue. The reference assemblies cannot be found on my build machine though VS2013 and .Net framework 4.5.1 are both installed. I'm actively pursuing this issue and will update if I discover anything useful.