# Visual Studio: after manually updating a reference in a project, the reference goes back to previous version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I am scratching my head about what is currently happening with one of the projects in my solution:

I have two projects (`InfrastructureSelenium` and `TestSelenium`) in the same solution. Both projects need a reference to the dll `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`

Project `InfrastructureSelenium`'s dll has the following properties:

```
(Name): Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
Alias: global
Copy Local: True
Description: Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
Embed Interop Types: False
File Type: Assembly
Identity: Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
Resolved: True
Runtime Version: v2.0.50727
Specific Version: True
Strong Name: True
Version: 10.1.0.0
```

Project `TestSelenium`, however, is using:

```
(Name): Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
Alias: global
Copy Local: False
Description: Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
Embed Interop Types: False
File Type: Assembly
Identity: Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
Resolved: True
Runtime Version: v2.0.50727
Specific Version: True
Strong Name: True
Version: 10.0.0.0
```

Note that `Path` and `Version` differ, and that is triggering the following error:

```
Assembly 'InfrastructureSelenium' with identity 'InfrastructureSelenium, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework' with identity 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

So I go to `TestSelenium`, remove the reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` and a add a new one to the same dll but with the correct version (`10.1.0.0`). That solves the problem and let's me compile and run the solution correctly, however if I save all, and check in the changes, the next time I open Visual Studio the same problem appears and I have to repeat it all over again.

What am I doing wrong and why is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` being reset each time I open Visual Studio?

Thanks for your time

Comment: If you are updating this through Nuget Manager, there is a Consolidate tab. You can try that option. If that doesn't work, unloading the project and reloading it works miracles sometimes.

Comment: Hello, I tried unloading and reloading the project and it did not fix the problem. However, is there a way to check if the dll is distributed by a nuget package?

Comment: "check in the changes" is where that must have gone wrong, they either did not get checked in or you're retrieving the old version again.  Ask a team member to look over your shoulder while you do this.

Comment: Can you check your .csproj files and make sure that the references are the same there?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934564/what-is-the-different-between-reference-assemblies-and-public-assemblies-in-visu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by removing all references to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework`and using NuGet package `MSTest.TestFramework v1.3.2` instead.

I am still not sure, however, what was causing the dll to be reset to version 10.0.0.0